# TensorBoard: Combine two graphs into one graph

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard, tensorboardx

I accidentally ran a model where the training loss goes to "Cos_BN Loss", and the validation loss go to "**Gen** Cos_BN Loss", that means that I have two separate graphs for train and validation (for the same type of loss).
I want to see them together on the same plot. How?

NOTE: I know I can just run again the model by calling the validation loss - the same name as the training loss, BUT it took around 3 days to ran, on 3 GPUs and I really don't want to train it again all over.

[Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lR5y.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the bottom there is a `download data` link that let's you save the data as a CSV file. You may need to enable it first (top left in following picture):

[image]

You can then import this e.g. using `pandas` and plot it to your liking using `matplotlib.